# Parsing nested HTML Lists using Python

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

My HTML code contains nested lists like this:

```html
<ul>
  <li>Apple</li>
  <li>Pear</li>
  <ul>
     <li>Cherry</li>
     <li>Orange</li>
     <ul>
        <li>Pineapple</li>
     </ul>
  </ul>
  <li>Banana</li>
</ul>
```

I need to parse them so they look like this:

```
+ Apple
+ Pear
++ Cherry
++ Orange
+++ Pineapple
+ Banana
```

I tried using BeautifulSoup, but I am stuck on how to consider the nesting in my code.

Example, where `x` contains the HTML code listed above:

```py
import bs4

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(x, "html.parser")
for ul in soup.find_all("ul"):
    for li in ul.find_all("li"):
        li.replace_with("+ {}\n".format(li.text))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use recursion:

```py
import bs4, re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
s = """
<ul>
  <li>Apple</li>
  <li>Pear</li>
  <ul>
     <li>Cherry</li>
     <li>Orange</li>
     <ul>
        <li>Pineapple</li>
     </ul>
  </ul>
  <li>Banana</li>
</ul>
"""
def indent(d, c = 0):
   if (s:=''.join(i for i in d.contents if isinstance(i, bs4.NavigableString) and i.strip())):
       yield f'{"+"*c} {s}'
   for i in d.contents:
      if not isinstance(i, bs4.NavigableString):
         yield from indent(i, c+1)

print('\n'.join(indent(soup(s, 'html.parser').ul)))
```

Output:

```
+ Apple
+ Pear
++ Cherry
++ Orange
+++ Pineapple
+ Banana
```

Answer (score 2):

It's somewhat of a hack, but you can do it using lxml instead:

```
import lxml.html as lh

uls = """[your html above]"""
doc = lh.fromstring(uls)
tree = etree.ElementTree(doc)
for e in doc.iter('li'):
        path = tree.getpath(e)
        print('+' * path.count('ul'), e.text)
```

Output:

```
+ Apple
+ Pear
++ Cherry
++ Orange
+++ Pineapple
+ Banana
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be easier to convert the `html` string to `markdown` with custom bullets. This can be done with [markdownify](https://github.com/matthewwithanm/python-markdownify):

```
import markdownify

formatted_html = markdownify.markdownify(x, bullets=['+', '++', '+++'], strip="ul")
```

result:

```
+ Apple
+ Pear
++ Cherry
++ Orange
+++ Pineapple
+ Banana
```